# How many different ways can 14 pencils be passed out to 6 different people? Some people are allowed no pencils.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

There are 2 questions that are very similar and I have the same answer to both but I don't think that's correct. Can you help me see the difference between the 2 questions.

1. We have 14 indistinguishable pencils and we want to hand out all of the pencils to 6 people (but we do not care if some of the people get no pencils.) How many different ways could this be done?

   My answer: 19 choose 14
2. We have 14 indistinguishable pencils and we want to hand out all of the pencils to 6 people and we want everyone to get at least one pencil. How many different ways could this be done?

   My answer: again 19 choose 14

Am I right or wrong or both? I'm confident one answer is 19 choose 14 but I'm not sure which. As you can see I'm a bit confused.

Comment: The first is correct.  Can you give reasons for this answer? - if so I think you will see why the second one is wrong, and how to fix it.

Comment: By using 5 dividers for the 6 people (think of the 6 people as "types"), putting the 14 pencils in the first section or divider and then counting the remaining sections/dividers which would be 5, so 14+5=19

Comment: @David Since each person would have 1 pencil, would it essentially be like handing out 8 pencils to the 6 people? If so, that would be 13 choose 8.

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1 is correct with the answer being $\binom{19}{14}$. Problem 2 is wrong and the correct answer is $\binom{13}{8}$. You reserve 1 pencil to each of the 6 people leaving you with 8 pencils left to pass out. The problem can be looked at as being how many different ways can we pass out 8 pencils to 6 people, and that would be $\binom{13}{8}$.

Comment: I helped a little with the formatting.  Please take a look at the edit I made... should help in the future.  Also, see: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation for additional reference.

Comment: @TravisJ I tried formatting them to look like what you did by this {19 \choose 14} but it didn't work.

Comment: @TravisJ Nevermind, I see what you did. $ \binom {19}{14}$

Answer (score 1):

I think the second question is easier and should be asked first.  Put the pencils in a row and there are $13$ spaces between them.  You need to select $5$ of these spaces to stop giving pencils to a given person and start giving them to the next, so there are ${13 \choose 5}={13 \choose 8}$ ways to do this.
six.
The first then comes from adding $1$ to the number given to each person.  You now have $20$ pencils to distribute to $6$ people, each of whom must get at least one.  The same logic says the answer is $19 \choose 5$, which happens to equal $19 \choose 14$

Comment: The first question results in an equation of the form $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$ with solutions in the nonnegative integers.  The number of solutions is the number of ways we can insert $k - 1$ addition symbols in a row of $n$ ones, which is $\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1} = \binom{n + k - 1}{n}$.  The second equation results in an equation of the same form with solutions in the positive integers.  The number of solutions is the number of ways we can fill $k - 1$ of the $n - 1$ spaces between the $n$ ones with addition signs, which is $\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$, as you clearly recognized.